# Как правильно передать значение из одного компонента в другой?

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть компонент, который содержит в себе форму модального окна. Есть второй компонент - кнопка. Кнопка расположена в отдельном файле. Подскажите, как мне передать данные из первого компонента в кнопку? Если я создаю новую кнопку на странице модального окна, то все работает, а если передаю данные, то нет.

```
<ButtonPrimary
  active={modalActive}
  setActive={setModalActive} >Записаться на прием</ButtonPrimary>
   <button onClick={onClickButon}>111</button>
```

Comment: попробуйте использовать hooks
в вашем случее можно использвать useState

Comment: приведите краткий пример использования компонентов

Answer (score 0):

Для передачи данных в другой компонент используются [пропсы](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#props). У вас они тоже присутствуют, например, в дочернем компоненте вы получите пропс `active` со значением `modalActive`

Чтобы работать с пропсом, его нужно не только объявить в родительском, но и получить через параметр в дочернем, например:

```
import React from "react";

const ButtonPrimary = ({ active, setActive, message }) => {
    console.log(active);
    
    // some your code

    return (
        <button onClick={onClickButon}>{message}</button>
    )
}

export default ButtonPrimary;
```

Родительский компонент может выглядеть так:

```
import React from "react";
import ButtonPrimary from "./ButtonPrimary ";

const customButton = () => {
    return (
        <ButtonPrimary
            active={modalActive}
            setActive={setModalActive} 
            message="Записаться на прием" />            
    )
} 
        
export defualt customButton;
```